# AMQPlib nodejs consumer task concurrency

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqp

I'm building a background task management system with rabbitmq and nodejs using the `amqlib` module.

Some of the tasks are really CPU-consuming, so if I'm launching a lot of them and I have only a few workers up, my server can get killed (using too much CPU).

I'm wondering if there is a way to create an amqp queue so that my consumers will only consume one task of this queue at a time (i.e. Before an ack or a reject, do not send a task of this kind to this consumer).
Or should I handle this myself in the code (maybe keeping a reference in my worker that I'm handling a task of this queue and rejecting all tasks of this queue while I'm executing the task ?).

Here is my sample code :

I'm creating the amqp connection like that

```
const amqpConn = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://localhost');
```

My queue name is `tasks` :

```js
amqpConn.then((conn) => {
  return conn.createChannel();
}).then((ch) => {
  return ch.assertQueue('tasks').then((ok) => {
    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(`something to do ${i}`));
  });
}).catch(console.warn);
```

And here is my consumer (I guess this is where I should do the work to limit only one concurrent task of this queue) :

```
amqpConn.then((conn) => {
  return conn.createChannel();
}).then((ch) => {
  return ch.assertQueue('tasks').then((ok) => {
    return ch.consume('tasks', (msg) => {
      if (msg !== null) {
        console.log(msg.content.toString());
        ch.ack(msg);
      }
    });
  });
}).catch(console.warn);
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with RabbitMQ, but take a look [at this](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_prefetch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it going by :

- creating a Channel per queue
- using the `prefetch_count` of the channel to limit the concurrency on a per-consumer basis

https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html

Answer (score 1):

`I'm wondering if there is a way to create an amqp queue so that my consumers will only consume one task of this queue at a time`

If this is what you really need then yes, simply have exactly one consumer and declare the queue exclusive. In that way one tasks is consumed at the time.

Comment: Thanks @cantSleepNow ! I knew I should have been more precise ;) I meat only consume "a given number" of tasks, not necessarily one.